# Jenkins. How to change file content

Tags: testing, jenkins

I've created a new project in Jenkins.
But now I want to change some information in my .properties file
How can I do that? (I've already read about Environment Injector, but I don't think, that it's what I need)

So, and one more questions - will this changes commit in file? (I don't want to do that)

Thank you!

Comment: [Content Replace](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Content+Replace+Plugin) is a plugin for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a scripted pipeline and you can use groovy for this task. For instance:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
File propsFile = new File(".properties")
props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream())
props.setProperty('key', 'value')
props.store(propsFile.newWriter(), null)
```

You open the properties file, change the value of a specific key element and write to the same file when done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making use of Jenkins and it is on a windows machine. You can make use of PowerShell to change the file content

Here in this example,
I am actually trying to modify the string occurrence 'Memory Usage' with Jenkins build number

```
(Get-Content C:\proj\Jenkins\workspace\QA.I9.Api\Sample.txt).replace('Memory Usage', $env:BUILD_NUMBER) | Set-Content C:\proj\Jenkins\workspace\QA.I9.Api\Sample.txt
```

Thanks,
xyzcoder.github.io